# Is it OK to send join message again on multicast when you have already joined the network?

Tags: sockets, multicast

My program will take a list of multicast addresses and will join those multicast groups.  Later on, the list of addresses may include new multicast addresses.  Existing multicast addresses won't be deleted.  As a requirement for my program, I cannot interrupt current multicast streams (so I cannot send a "leave" message).  I had planned to cycle through list and send join messages to the multicast addresses in my list, without tracking which groups I've already joined.  Is this OK?

I saw the post about sending join messages when receiving a Membership Query, but in this instance, I'm not responding to a Membership Query report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join a group multiple times, if that's what you mean. Your description isn't clear. But I don't see what's so hard about knowing which groups are new and which are already current.

The Membership Query message is for UDP and routers, not for applications.